# useEffect hook problem, use redux to get data from backend to frontend

Tags: redux, react-redux

Hello i am new to programming, and i have learn to use MERN to make a sign up,i have no issue with backend but when i tried to use redux ,i have this problem in the frontend

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s5kOx.png)

This is the code for the SignInScreen.js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../actions/userAction'

export const SignInScreen = (props, history) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }
  const { search } = useLocation()
  const redirectInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get('redirect')
  const redirect = redirectInUrl ? redirectInUrl : '/'

  const userlogin = useSelector((state) => state.userlogin)
  const { userInfo, loading, error } = userlogin
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect)
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect])
```

I dont know what wrong with the code,but i do know that it connected with the redux store which have reducer,action and constant..this is for the redux store.js

```
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

import {
  userLoginReducer,
} from './reducers/userReducer'


const userInfo = localStorage.getItem('userInfo')
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userInfo'))
  : null

const initialState = {
  userLogin: { userInfo },
}
const reducer = combineReducers({
  userLogin: userLoginReducer,
})

const middleware = [thunk]

const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware))
)
export default store
```

This is for constant

```
export const USER_LOGIN_REQUEST = 'USER_LOGIN_REQUEST'
export const USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS'
export const USER_LOGIN_FAIL = 'USER_LOGIN_FAIL'

export const USER_LOGOUT = 'USER_LOGOUT'
```

this is userReducer.js

```
import {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
  USER_LOGOUT,
} from '../constants/userConstant'

function userLoginReducer(state = {}, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true }
    case USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, userInfo: action.payload }
    case USER_LOGIN_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload }
    case USER_LOGOUT:
      return {}
    default:
      return state
  }
}

export userLoginReducer
```

and lastly for user.js

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import {
  USER_LOGIN_REQUEST,
  USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS,
  USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
} from '../constants/userConstant'


const login = (email, password) => async (dispatch) => {
  try {
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST })
    const config = { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
    const { data } = await Axios.post(
      '/api/users/login',
      { email, password },
      config
    )
    dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: data })
    localStorage.setItem('userInfo', JSON.stringify(data))
  } catch (error) {
    dispatch({
      type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
      payload:
        error.response && error.response.data.message
          ? error.response.data.message
          : error.message,
    })
  }
}

export login
```

I just want to get the data into the userInfo but it dont recognized them and said it is a TypeError..I hope u can help me with this..im using the redux latest version

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in `userLoginReducer`. Each reducer should return a complete new copy of the store.

If you return just the changes, the object you return replaces the entire state.
For example in this code:

```js
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
}
```

The state `{ userLogin: { userInfo } }` will be replaced with `{ loading: true }`. Then you will not have `userLogin` anymore in the state. That's why you get the error.

To overcome this problem, spread the previous state in returned object (for all actions):

```js
  switch (action.type) {
    case USER_LOGIN_REQUEST:
      return { ....state, loading: true }; // ...state copies exist state to the new copy of state
}
```

Note: To easily solve similar bugs in the future, I recommend to use [redux devtools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) extension. It is a great extension for debugging and look at changes in redux store.

Comment: Suggesting to use RTK and Immer might also help him to avoid these issues!

Comment: @CesarePolonara Can help too. RTK is the new standard of redux, for very good reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that but still cannot fix my problem,this is the rest of my signinScreen,js

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux'
import { Link, useLocation, useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom'
import { login } from '../actions/userAction'

export const SignInScreen = (props, history) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    dispatch(login(email, password))
  }
  const { search } = useLocation()
  const redirectInUrl = new URLSearchParams(search).get('redirect')
  const redirect = redirectInUrl ? redirectInUrl : '/'

  const userlogin = useSelector((state) => state.userlogin)
  const { userInfo, loading, error } = userlogin
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    if (userInfo) {
      navigate(redirect)
    }
  }, [navigate, userInfo, redirect])

  return (
    <Container className="small-container">
      <h1 className="my-3">Sign In</h1>
      <Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="email"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="password"
            required
            onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
          />
        </Form.Group>
        <div className="mb-3">
          <Button type="submit">Sign In</Button>
        </div>
        <div className="mb-3">
          New Customer?{' '}
          <Link to={`/signup?redirect=${redirect}`}>Create new account</Link>
        </div>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  )
}
```

it still show the same error like before,i have no idea to solve this

Comment: Hello Mohamad, it seems you're trying to ask a question. But you've posted it as an answer to this question. I would encourage you to ask a separate question of your own separately. If required you can add a link to this question in your new question to explain things better.